# tengo un problema con CKeditor y laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola Tengo un problema con ck editor, en local funciona y edita correctamente pero cuando lo he subido al servidor no edita y ademas muestra las etiquetas.

Recien estoy probando a web en el servidor

https://chicoteca.pe/chicotecas/nueva-prueba

```html
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) }}

<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categorias') }}
 {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::label('name', 'Titulo de la Publicación') }}
 {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::label('slug', 'URL Amigable') }}
 {{ Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'slug'])}}
</div>

  
   
<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::label('body', 'Descripción') }}
 {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 {{ Form::label('youtube', 'ID Youtube video') }}
 {{ Form::text('youtube', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'youtube']) }}
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm']) }}
</div>


@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name, #slug").stringToSlug({
   callback: function(text){
    $("#slug").val(text);
   }
  });
 });

 CKEDITOR.config.height = 400;
 CKEDITOR.config.width = 'auto';

 CKEDITOR.replace('body');
</script>
@endsection
```

En local funciona perfectamente pero en el servidor me aparece con las etiquetas de esta forma:

[image: imagen de muestra de como edita el ckeditor en el servidor, este es el error que tengo]

Comment: Compartí el código y publicá que error estás obteniendo.

Comment: hola edite la respuesta con la parte del codigo donde añado ck editor y ademas pegue una imagen del error que me da en la web. Gracias

Comment: Revisaste en la base de datos como se está guardando los campos? Si ahí las etiquetas están bien, el problema es cuando mostrás la información, no cuando la guardas. Pone más info: Cómo guardas en la DB? Cómo mostrás los datos en la vista? Con tan poca información es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, con eso fue suficiente para darme cuenta que estaba pidiendo: <p>{{$post->body}}</p> , ese era el problema, la solucion fue ésta: {!! $post->body !!}